# Cloud Functions are only deployed if tests are passed using Github Actions

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, firebase-realtime-database, github-actions, cicd

Few points for better understanding

1. This is the warning that I am getting after all of my test cases were passed and when I get this warning. It stucks the process of deployment and the warning keeps getting repeated.
2. If I run these test cases on my local machine it dosen't give me this warning.
3. I have checked all the credentials and I didn't find any issue in them.

Question.
Is there any thing I can do in the YML file so whenever this warning encountered it automatically complete it's job and move to next process of deployment?

Warning: Warning: @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: ***"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND"."***

[image: Warning message]

YML file
This is my YML file

```
name: Deploy Cloud Functions
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      function_name:
        description: 'Enter the name of the function to deploy'
        default: ''
      include_list:
        description: 'Enter a comma-separated list of function names to include in the deployment'
        default: ''
      exclude_list:
        description: 'Enter a comma-separated list of function names to exclude from the deployment'
        default: ''
   
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0 
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
      - name: Cache NPM modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/functions/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: cd functions && npm ci
      - name: Install test dependencies
        run: |
          cd functions && 
          npm install --save-dev mocha chai &&
          npm install -g nyc
      - name: Add nyc to PATH
        run: export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
      - name: Create SA key
        run: echo '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}' > $HOME/gcloud.json
      - name: Run tests and Create coverage report
        run: |
          cd functions && npm test
      - name: Get changed files
        if: always()
        id: changed-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v35
        with:
          since_last_remote_commit: true 
      - name: Store changed files in a file
        if: always()
        run: |
          touch changes_files.txt
          echo "${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" > changed_files.txt
          touch differences.txt
          git diff --name-only $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD > differences.txt
      - name: Set Version Environment Variable
        if: always()
        id: set-version-env
        run: |
          cd functions
          echo "VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Set Last Tag Environment Variable
        if: always()
        id: set-last-tag-env
        run: echo "LAST_TAG=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Send mail with release details
        if: always()
        uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3
        with:
          server_address: smtp.gmail.com
          server_port: 465
          secure: true
          username: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          password: ${{secrets.MAIL_PASSWORD}}
          subject: |
            Cloud Functions deployed: ${{ job.status }}
          to: test@test.com
          from: Demo <test@test.com> 
          attachments: |
            changed_files.txt
            differences.txt
          priority: low
        env:
          VERSION: ${{ env.VERSION }}
          LAST_TAG: ${{ env.LAST_TAG }}
      - name: Deploy Cloud Functions
        run: |
          export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$HOME/gcloud.json
          cd functions && npm test && npm run lint && 
          if [[ -z "${{ github.event.inputs.function_name }}" && -z "${{ github.event.inputs.include_list }}" && -z "${{ github.event.inputs.exclude_list }}" ]]; then
            npx firebase-tools deploy --only functions --json --PROJECT-ID
          elif [[ ! -z "${{ github.event.inputs.function_name }}" ]]; then
            npx firebase-tools deploy --only functions:${{ github.event.inputs.function_name }} --json --PROJECT-ID
          elif [[ ! -z "${{ github.event.inputs.include_list }}" ]]; then
            npx firebase-tools deploy --only functions --include "${{ github.event.inputs.include_list }}" --json --PROJECT-ID
          elif [[ ! -z "${{ github.event.inputs.exclude_list }}" ]]; then
            npx firebase-tools deploy --only functions --exclude "${{ github.event.inputs.exclude_list }}" --json --PROJECT-ID
          fi
          true
enter code here
```

Comment: Please share your error in text. And share how are you setting up your pipeline and tests, it seems that you need to pass your firebase token from the pipeline. And if it's a unit test why you'd not just mock it?

Comment: @Fcmam5 I have edited the warning text and for this ( 'share how are you setting up your pipeline and tests, ') part u want the YML file?

Comment: Yes, and how are you passing secrets to you firebase `initializeApp`

Comment: I have attached my YML file. Please check

Comment: There is an issue with the app credentials. Are you sure the app has the necessary permission to access the Google OAuth2 service? Because as you have mentioned it is running successfully locally.It is advisable don't modify YAML file before resolving warning issue @Sahil